# Bluetooth not working on MSI GS60 2QE

Tags: windows, windows-8.1, mouse, bluetooth, windows-10

I have a problem with my Bluetooth and honestly the Killer Network card makes me angry. The bluetooth worked fine since I've bought my computer, but earlier a bug has happened with bluetooth on Windows 8.1 which it has solved itself (I don't know how), and now with Windows 10 (but it's not because of the system) the same bug has happened but it hasn't solved itself this time! The bug is bluetooth worked, and suddenly it stopped working: it seems to works perfectly, Windows search to pair devices, but it doesn't find any device. And the device I want to pair is only a Microsoft Sculpt Comfort mouse, which works perfectly (I've tested it on my Android phone). I don't understand because this bug has appeared suddenly and now bluetooth not working anymore (and I just bought my bluetooth mouse ^^ ). Drivers are installed and working, I have no problem with my Windows 10, I've made a clean install and it changes nothing, so this is a problem with the card I suppose(?). Any idea?

My config:
PC: MSI GS60 2QE Ghost Pro
OS: Windows 10 (activated)
Network card: Qualcomm Atheros (driver: Qualcomm Atheros AR3012 Bluetooth 4.0 + HS)
Ask for other things!

Thanks! <3

PS: Sorry for my English, I'm French.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found the solution! And this is a really strange solution... ^^ You have to go on [this page](http://www.killernetworking.com/product-support/driver-downloads/bluetooth-drivers) and even if you are on Windows 10, you have to download and install the Windows 8 driver! Grr 3 days to find that... ^^

Answer (score 1):

Likely your issue resides within the device drivers. Most manufacturers have not certified their drivers for Windows 10, and as such unexpected (in)operation may occur.

According to the [manufacturer](http://www.msi.com/support/nb/GS60-2PL-Ghost.html#down-driver) (MSI) they have drivers for Windows 7 and Windows 8.1 on that model, 64-bit architectures only.

Aside from the officially supported route, the best recommendation anyone could make is to retrieve the Windows 8.1 and Windows 7 drivers from MSI and test installing to see if either produce desirable results. Of course, reboots between driver installs/uninstalls would be necessary to re-initiate them most likely.

Comment: Unfortunately this is not a solution: yesterday Windows 10 didn't activate so I've reinstalled Windows 8.1 and I took the opportunity to test bluetooth, and it has not worked even on Windows 8. And the bluetooth has worked during few hours in Windows 10 before it stops working! This is why I'm almost sure the problem is not Windows 10.

Comment: Right, the problem is not Windows 10, nor Windows 8 - it is the drivers supporting your device. You can check to see if there is more updated versions of the drivers from the manufacturer of the Bluetooth chipset itself (e.g. Intel, Atheros) and test that. Often PC manufacturers do not update their driver repositories.

Comment: Nop, the majority of my drivers are automatically installed via Windows Update (and I have much less problems with Windows 10 strangely ^^ ) and when I install manually I search directly on the site of the card manufacturer (Atheros, NVIDIA...)

Comment: At this point if it's not a software issue (which it could absolutely be...) it could be hardware. Is the chip overheating and faulting? Can the chip be re-seated? I see you commented that you cannot open the device for warranty reasons...

Perhaps the realistic option would be to open a ticket with MSI in that case. :-(

Comment: In appearance all hardware works perfectly, no overheating or anything. But Killer Networks cards are absolutely crap, and it's perfectly possible this is an hardware issue, so I've contacted MSI just before.
What "re-seated" means? :-° (sorry I'm French and Google translate this as an equivalent of "sit down again" ^^ )

Comment: Very sorry to confuse! To re-seat something is a slang sort of term for "to remove from the board, and plug back in again." Sometimes cards can lose their contact for who knows what reason, or simply power being lost from it restores normal operation with a "clean start".

Comment: Okay thanks ^^ So thanks for your responses, now I juste have to wait for the response of MSI...